# How to echo value from one file to another file while copying or writing in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, file

I want to write and copy a file. And I need to `echo` the value while writing and copying the file.

Kindly check my code:

```
<?php 
$pages = array("story1", "story2", "story3","story4","story5","story6");
$length = count($pages);

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $myFile = "newfile-in-{$pages[$i]}.php";

    if (file_exists($myFile)) {
        echo copy("expcontent.php","newfile-in-{$pages[$i]}.php");
    }else{
        $myfile = fopen("newfile-in-{$pages[$i]}.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 

        $txt = "Mickey {$pages[$i]}\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = "Hello Mouse\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    }
}
```

In my `expcontent.php`:

```
<p>Kids <?php echo $pages[$i];?>!</p>
```

Everything is working fine. The new files have been created and have copied the file perfectly. But the output is:

```
Kids, !   
Kids, !   
Kids, !   
Kids, !   
Kids, !
```

Expected Output:

```
Kids Story1!
Kids Story2!
Kids Story3!
Kids Story4!
Kids Story5!
Kids Story6!
```

I am not getting the right output or I think the `$pages[$i]` value on `expcontent.php`.

Kindly check my code and correct me.
Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.
Thank You.

Comment: Copying a file doesn't execute the PHP that's in it. It's just copied verbatim.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement some kind of template system. There are many libraries and frameworks that do this, you should use one of them instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply! And while writing a file? While writing a file can we write kids story1! if yes how?

Comment: When you're writing the file, the variable is expanded when you do the assignment `$txt = "Mickey {$pages[$i]}\n";`

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside string literals, not strings that are read from somewhere else.

Comment: I don't see the closing php tag in the top file.. is that a copy-to-question error?

Comment: @RachelGallen As long as there is no HTML/CSS etc. below the PHP, there is no need to use the `?>` closing tag.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ah right. Missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments under the question [in addition to the question], I understand that you want to expand a story by writing out file contents, as opposed to just the name of the file.

If you have created "chapters" of a story and stored them as separate files, you can use `include` to write out the contents:

e.g.

```
<?php
    $title="My Kids Story";
    include "chapter1.php";
    include "chapter2.php";
?>
```

You can store the chapters as .php OR you can use an alternate extension and block direct access to it [from users] in your server configuration (`httpd.conf`on apache) file. [More about that here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/webnut/ch16_02.htm)

e.g. put this in your config and include chapter1.inc instead of .php

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: p.s look at [chapter 9](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/webnut/ch16_09.htm) to see an example function of incorporating a variable value

Answer (score -1):

You are just copying the file, but it's never executing. You can read the file contents and execute it with [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Be sure to check the docs.

> **Caution** 
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
$pages = array("story1", "story2", "story3","story4","story5","story6");

foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $myFile = "newfile-in-{$page}.php";

  if (file_exists($myFile)) {
    $content = file_get_contents('expcontent.php');
    $newcontent = eval($content);
    file_put_contents($myFile, $newcontent);
  } else {
    $myfile = fopen("newfile-in-{$page}.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
    $txt = "Mickey {$page}\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Hello Mouse\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  }
}
```

From the manual again:

> The code must not be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags.

So you have to change your `expcontent.php` to:

```
?><p>Kids <?php echo $page;?>!</p>
```

or

```
echo "<p>Kids {$page}!</p>";
```

Another, safer way of doing this whithout the use of eval, would be to capture the output of your second page (this is the if block only and it should work with your original `expcontent.php`).

```
ob_start();
include 'expcontent.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($myFile, $content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But not worked even it removed all my content ie: Kids Story2! and the file size reduced 24b to 0b

Comment: @Sarah Sorry, there were a coupe errors in there, but that *should* work.